# How to make Jersey framework scan resources defined in external jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs, jax-ws

I want to use Jersey Framework 2.33 for using rest api. my web.xml is like :

```
<!-- Added By Habil Harati -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestWebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.dpdouran.restapi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestWebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xforce/restapiservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- End Habil Harati -->
```

I define "org.dpdouran.restapi" in another project and add that project to the classpath of this project and then I add a class like this to this package

```
package org.dpdouran.restapi;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("apireader")
public class ApiDataReader {

    @GET
    @Path("get")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

the problem is that when I add the package "org.dpdouran.restapi" to the main project it works correctly but when I cut the package and paste it in another project and then add that project as dependency in classpath it doesn't work.
Please help me solve this problem. I cant place that package in my main project.
I bound to use classpath and eclipse and I can't go with maven.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by chance. I create package in my main project without any classes in it, then I create the same package in my another project and I placed all of my classes there. Now Jersey framework can scan those classes and understand annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If you main project is a Dynamic Web Project, you just need to go into its Deployment Assembly property page and Add the other project to it.